# Error while executing external function in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, dll, plsql

I have set `SET EXTPROC_DLLS = Any` in `extproc.ora` file

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY oraclelib AS 'D:\Oracle\db_home\bin';

CREATE OR REPLACE LIBRARY clib AS 'ConsoleApplication2.dll' IN oraclelib;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION addition(
    a   NUMBER,
    b   NUMBER
)RETURN NUMBER AS EXTERNAL LIBRARY clib NAME "addfoo" LANGUAGE C;
/

DECLARE
    c NUMBER;
BEGIN
    c := addition(4, 8);
END;
```

And I am getting an error

```
Error report -
ORA-06520: PL/SQL: Error loading external library
ORA-06512: at "HRCOPY.ADDITION", line 1
ORA-06512: at line 4
06520. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: Error loading external library"
*Cause:    An error was detected by PL/SQL trying to load the external
           library dynamically.
*Action:   Ensure that the dynamic library exists, that it is installed
           correctly and that it is not corrupt or otherwise unreadable by
           the operating system.  Also, ensure that the library path in the
           LIBRARY object is correct, including the values of any environment
           variables used in the library path and the directory path values
           of any DIRECTORY objects used by the LIBRARY object.
```

There is only one function in the `DLL` file with name addfoo. 
Can anyone please tell what are the correct steps for creating an external function?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you configured `tnsnames.ora` and `listener.ora` [as it says in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_externproc.htm#ADFNS703)? Your directory `oraclelib` is pointing to an OS directory on the DB server, isn't it?

Comment: I am using oracle 19C, I guess configuring  ```tnsnames.ora``` and  ```tnsnames.ora``` for this version.  ```'D:\Oracle\db_home\bin'``` is present on the oracle server.

Comment: Yes. Oracle 19c is just a point release of Oracle 12c R2.

Comment: Or is it possible if there is an issue with the ```DLL``` file?

Comment: The error message's explanation indicates that this is a broad error with many possible causes. You need to go through all of them until you find whatever is causing the problem. I proposed file configuration as a place to start simply because your question doesn't mention it.

Comment: Ok, I will try to configure both files but not sure how to configure them.

Answer (score 1):

**Dear All,
I have recently migrated our application from 10g to 19c and encountered with this challenges. Below is the complete solution which I did to fix it:-**

- Re-create external library(.so file) in Linux server.

> - Pull demo_rdbms.mk and env_rdbms.mk files from
>   /opt/oracle/appdir/product/19.0.0/rdbms/ location and put into
>   /opt/appfilepath Location.
>   - Add a link into demo_rdbms.mk file to call env_rdbms.mk file.
>   - Go to /opt/appfilepath location and run this command to generate the
>   sofilename.so(external .so file) file:-
>
>   ```
>   make -f demo_rdbms.mk sofilename 2>&1
>   ```

- Add entry in tnsname.ora file:-

> ```
>   EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA_APPNAME = 
>   (DESCRIPTION = 
>        (ADDRESS_LIST = 
>    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC8)) 
>        ) 
>       (CONNECT_DATA = 
>        (SID = PLSExtProcAppname) 
>    (PRESENTATION = RO) 
>        ) 
>     )
> ```

- Add entry in tnsname.ora file:-

> ```
> SID_LIST_EXTAPPNAME_LISTENER =
>   (SID_LIST =
>     (SID_DESC =
>        (SID_NAME = PLSExtProcAppname)
>        (ORACLE_HOME = /opt/oracle/dbdir/product/19.0.0/db1)
>        (TNS_ADMIN = /opt/Appname/extproc)
>        (PROGRAM = extproc)
>        (ENVS = 
>        "EXTPROC_DLLS=ANY:/opt/appfilepath/sofilename.so,
>        LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/dbdir/product/19.0.0/db1/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH")
>        )
>        )
> ```

- Create DB link using Agent clause pointing to location of external Library

  ```
    DECLARE
       l_inst VARCHAR2(20);
    BEGIN
       l_inst := sys_context('USERENV','DB_NAME');

      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
       'create or replace library extfile_cmd as ''/opt/appname/' || l_inst || 
       '/apppath/sofilename.so'' AGENT  ''extproc_link_appname''';
    END;
  ```
- Test the external procedure If it is working fine using following test script:-

  ```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION new_fun_2 (ip_Cmd IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2
    AS
      EXTERNAL LIBRARY extfile_cmd
      NAME "sh"
      LANGUAGE C;
       /
     declare
          l_java_return       varchar2(100);
      begin
        l_java_return :=new_fun_2('ls');
        dbms_output.put_line(l_java_return);
      end;
  ```